# LSTM Keras: Reshape Input Data

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, autoencoder

I want to build an LSTM Autoencoder model for customer behavior and detect anomalies. The activity dataset looks like:

```
customer_id               features
C1                   [[1,2,1,0,1],[2,2,1,1,0],[1,2,3,1,1],[0,3,2,1,1]]
C2                   [[2,1,1,4,1],[3,2,1,1,4],[2,2,3,1,2]]
..............................................
Cn                   [[2,3,1,4,1],[2,1,1,1,0],[4,2,2,1,2],[3,3,2,1,1], [2,3,2,1,2], [1,3,2,2,1]]
```

Here, the number of features for all samples is same i.e. 5. However, the no. of samples are different for different Customers. There are N Customers.
In such case how to separate train and test data and how to reshape input data for the LSTM model?

As of now,

1. I am considering e.g. 80% of samples from each customer data as training and remaining as testing.
2. Trying to reshape the input as : (no_of_customers, timesteps, no_of_features) = (n, #no_of_samples, 5)
   . This array is not supported since we can not have a numpy array with varying timesteps.

Comment: I have written an answer, see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In such scenarios you need to use padding. refer [tensorflow padding guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding)

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

# club all features (c1, c2 ... features, I clubbed c1. c2 only) as a below:    
input1 = [[[1,2,1,0,1],[2,2,1,1,0],[1,2,3,1,1],[0,3,2,1,1]],
         [[2,1,1,4,1],[3,2,1,1,4],[2,2,3,1,2]]]

padded_input = pad_sequences(input1, padding='post')
print(padded_input)
```

**you can set *maxlen* argument as well, depends on maximum list given for the customers**

Comment: I have split the input data as X_train and X_test. If we pad sequence of zeros for the customers who have fewer data samples, what happens in the overall result of the model? Does it create difference in the model performance?

Comment: no it won't,  padding and masking module by itself take care of the zero padding. please read the link once, you will get to know.

Comment: one more thing, make sure you pad your test data as well. let me know if things are clear at your side.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I will try and get back to you.

Comment: sure and ask anytime !, if it works for you, do mark as answered :)

Comment: I've divided data into two sets Xtrain and Xtest and padded the zeros. Then X_train = np.array(X_train) and X_test = np.array(X_test). After reshape, the X_train has size (1000,450,40) and X_test has size (1000,150,40).


The model is sequential. e.g. inputs = Input(shape = (timesteps, n_features))
L1 = LSTM(encoding_dim, activation ='relu', return_sequences=True, 
          kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00))(inputs)
.............


I'm confused about where to put mask_zero=True.